# Keep one worker running continuously in Unicorn Nginx Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, unicorn

There is a long delay when I first load up my website after deploying with capistrano. After that the new requests are really fast. Then after an hour or so when I load the site again, the first request take forerver. Often it even returns the 500 error page (I am guessing becuase of the timeout). Then when I hit refresh, it loads up in an instant.

I am guessing that after a certain amount of time when a new request is received by the server, it reloads the entire rails environment. Is there any way I can just keep one copy of the environment running constantly?

Here is my unicorn config:

```
root = "/home/user/apps/app_name/current"
working_directory root
pid "#{root}/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid"
stderr_path "#{root}/log/unicorn.log"
stdout_path "#{root}/log/unicorn.log"

listen "/tmp/unicorn.app_name.sock"
worker_processes 2
timeout 60
```

Production.log

```
Started GET "/" for 1.2.3.4 at 2012-08-10 09:59:13 +0000
Connecting to database specified by database.yml


Started GET "/" for 1.2.3.4 at 2012-08-10 10:03:14 +0000
Connecting to database specified by database.yml


Started GET "/" for 1.2.3.4 at 2012-08-10 10:04:38 +0000
Processing by PagesController#home as HTML
  Rendered layouts/_top_bar_public.html.erb (1.1ms)
  Rendered shared/_flash.html.erb (0.3ms)
  Rendered pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (8.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 48ms (Views: 47.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Unicorn.log

```
E, [2012-08-10T10:00:14.449348 #6005] ERROR -- : worker=1 PID:4951 timeout (61s > 60s), killing
E, [2012-08-10T10:00:14.458442 #6005] ERROR -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 4951 SIGKILL (signal 9)> worker=1
I, [2012-08-10T10:00:14.458796 #6005]  INFO -- : worker=1 spawning...
I, [2012-08-10T10:00:14.465259 #6458]  INFO -- : worker=1 spawned pid=6458
I, [2012-08-10T10:00:14.465639 #6458]  INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list
I, [2012-08-10T10:00:18.115613 #6458]  INFO -- : worker=1 ready
E, [2012-08-10T10:04:15.706315 #6005] ERROR -- : worker=0 PID:4929 timeout (61s > 60s), killing
E, [2012-08-10T10:04:15.716064 #6005] ERROR -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 4929 SIGKILL (signal 9)> worker=0
I, [2012-08-10T10:04:15.716566 #6005]  INFO -- : worker=0 spawning...
I, [2012-08-10T10:04:15.723733 #6461]  INFO -- : worker=0 spawned pid=6461
I, [2012-08-10T10:04:15.724111 #6461]  INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list
I, [2012-08-10T10:04:19.298475 #6461]  INFO -- : worker=0 ready
```

ps ux:

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
deployer  6005  0.0  3.3 149880 20292 ?        Sl   Aug01   0:15 unicorn master -D -c /home/deployer/apps/app_name
deployer  6458  0.2  9.6 234544 58036 ?        Sl   10:00   0:03 unicorn worker[1] -D -c /home/deployer/apps/app_name
deployer  6461  0.2  9.3 232924 56564 ?        Sl   10:04   0:03 unicorn worker[0] -D -c /home/deployer/apps/app_name
deployer  6563  0.0  0.2  73352  1804 ?        S    10:29   0:00 sshd: deployer@pts/0
deployer  6564 13.3  1.3  25744  8196 pts/0    Ss   10:29   0:00 -bash
deployer  6743  0.0  0.2  16872  1264 pts/0    R+   10:29   0:00 ps ux
```

Answer (score 1):

This is odd behaviour since on deployment it should cleanup and touch tmp/restart to restart the server.

The config above suggests that there are 2 processes these are the worker and the master processes of unicorn you can check them out by inserting `$:.ps ux` in your command line

To get a more clear idea of what is going wrong you could make an ssh connection to your webserver and tail both the production.log and the unicorn.err using `$tail -f log/file.extention`

Comment: When I enter in '%:.ps ux' I get 'bash: fg: %:.ps: no such job'. And I've updated my question with the log info. Thanks for your help!

Comment: the $:. part show that it is a console command, just run ps ux EDIT: my bad I saw I put a % instead of $

Comment: The thing with these logs is they show you every single behaviour what I would like you to do is when you feel like the website is slowing down check the logs for weird behaviour and check the processes (ps ux) and see if the time running either long or short this would indicate that unicorn restarted its master. then we can go further

Comment: Alright thanks! I'll go ahead and try to pin point the problem.